# connectionDidFinishLoading is not invoked immediately

Tags: objective-c, ios4

My app will call a webservice to load data. Every time I send the request, the method connection:didReceiveData: is invoked very quick, and I put a NSLog statement inside this method, I can see that the data I receive is just the same as shown in HTTP header field Content-Length. So there should be no more data need to be received. In fact, connection:didReceiveData is not invoked any more. But my connectionDidFinishLoading is invoked exactly 1 minute later every time. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: When you hit the service with curl or a web browser do you get an indication that the completion of the request is shorter?

Comment: Since it is a webservice, I don't know how to use curl to make that webservice call, I just wonder if it can. However, if my program don't make the webservice call probably, that is the server return error message, it is quick. The delay only happen when I get the data correctly. I just wonder if the server side problem because I use my program to call another webservice which is public and free on the web, I got the result very quick as well.

Comment: Now I wonder how NSURLConnection to judge if data is received completed and then call the connectionDidFinishLoading method. Something like a '\0' to indicate the data is finish transferring? Or just compare the content length in the HTTP header and the bytes are received? If it is judge by '\0', the server side does not send this byte so my program wait until it is timeout internally(that's why it delays exactly 1 minute to call connectionDidFinishLoading every time?) Just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

`connection:didReceiveData:` is called many times.  You must take that data and append it to the data that you got the last time it was called.  Only when you receive `connectionDidFinishLoading` you know that the transfer is complete and you have all that data.

So just because you receive some data doesn't mean it's done.  It's very likely that the server is taking that long to finalize the request or you other issues somewhere in your code, like excessive data processing in your callbacks delaying the execution of the final callback.

Comment: No, I put a NSLog statement inside the connection:didReceiveData: method, I am sure it is called only one time in this case.